# Spark Scala Cassandra connector delete all all rows is failing with IllegalArgumentException requirement failed Exception

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

Create table -

```
CREATE TABLE test.word_groups (group text, word text, count int,PRIMARY KEY (group,word));
```

Insert Data -

```
INSERT INTO test.word_groups (group , word , count ) VALUES ( 'A-group', 'raj', 0) ;
INSERT INTO test.word_groups (group , word , count ) VALUES ( 'b-group', 'jaj', 0) ;
INSERT INTO test.word_groups (group , word , count ) VALUES ( 'A-group', 'raff', 3) ;

 SELECT * FROM word_groups ;

 group   | word | count
---------+------+-------
 b-group |  jaj |     0
 A-group | raff |     3
 A-group |  raj |     0
```

Script -

```scala
val cassandraUrl = "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra"
val wordGroup: Map[String, String] = Map("table" ->"word_groups", 
  "keyspace" -> "test", "cluster" -> "test-cluster")
val groupData = {spark.read.format(cassandraUrl).options(wordGroup).load()
  .where(col("group") === "b-group")}
groupData.rdd.deleteFromCassandra("sunbird_courses", "word_groups")
```

Exception -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid row size: 3 instead of 2.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.SqlRowWriter.readColumnValues(SqlRowWriter.scala:23)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.SqlRowWriter.readColumnValues(SqlRowWriter.scala:12)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.BoundStatementBuilder.bind(BoundStatementBuilder.scala:102)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.next(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:105)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.next(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:30)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:30)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:229)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:198)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:112)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:129)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:198)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.delete(TableWriter.scala:194)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$deleteFromCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:119)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$deleteFromCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
21/08/11 09:01:24 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 2953, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid row size: 3 instead of 2.
```

Spark Version - 2.4.4 and
Spark Cassandra Connector version - 2.5.0

Spark Cassandra connector doc link - https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#deleting-rows-and-columns

I'm trying to delete all records of those columns including primary keys.

Is there is any workaround for it ?

**FYI - I need to delete all the records of group "A-group" from the word_groups table including primary keys / partition keys**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's interesting change in 2.5.x, that I wasn't aware of - you now need to have a correct row size even if `keyColumns` is specified, it worked without it before - looks like a bug for me.

You need to leave only the primary key when deleting the whole row - change delete to the:

```scala
groupData.select("group", "word").rdd.deleteFromCassandra("test", "word_groups")
```

but in your case, it's even better to delete based on the partition key column - in this case you'll have only one tombstone (you still need to select only necessary columns):

```scala
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
{groupData.select("group").rdd
  .deleteFromCassandra("test", "word_groups", keyColumns = SomeColumns("group"))}
```

And you don't even need to read the input data from Cassandra - if you know the values of partition key, then you can just create the RDD & delete data (similar to shown in the [doc](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/5_saving.md#example-deleting-a-range-from-a-partition)):

```scala
case class Key (group:String)
{ sc.parallelize(Seq(Key("b-group")))
   .deleteFromCassandra("test", "word_groups", keyColumns = SomeColumns("group"))}
```

Comment: Is it not possible without mentioning the SomeColumns? is there any other way to delete without mentioning the primary keys?

Comment: ```java.io.IOException: Failed to prepare statement DELETE "group", "word" FROM "test"."word_groups" WHERE "group" = :"group" AND "word" = :"word": Invalid identifier group for deletion (should not be a PRIMARY KEY part)
 at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.com$datastax$spark$connector$writer$TableWriter$$prepareStatement(TableWriter.scala:142)``` getting this exception if you execute the above query (`SomeColumns("group", "word")`)

Comment: `groupData.rdd.deleteFromCassandra("sunbird_courses", "word_groups",keyColumns = SomeColumns("word", "group"))` Same exception error i'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid row size: 3 instead of 2.` @Alex Ott

Comment: sorry, it looks like that there was behavior change in 2.5.x, I've updated the answer

Comment: Especially we have to select the primary keys and invoke delete task right

Comment: If we select all the primary keys will delete the entire row or just those primary keys will get deleted? what happens to other columns `count` col ?  ```groupData.select("group", "word").rdd.deleteFromCassandra("test", "word_groups")```

Comment: if you delete primary key columns the whole row goes away. But in your case it's better to delete by just partition key.  I recommend to look into this blog post that explains differences between deletes of individual cells, delete by full primary key & partition key only: https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html

Comment: Thanks, so it will create tombstones right? then we have to run the compaction task to fix the tombstones righ? Could you please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: any delete in Cassandra will create a tombstone. But there are different types of tombstones.  When you delete by primary key, it will create 1 tombstone for all cells in the row independent of how many columns are in the table.  If you delete by partition key, then it will create 1 tombstone for all rows in that partition. Look into blog post that I put into updated commentary

Comment: After deleting I still see sometime records are available when I try to query using cqlsh.  I found these are the logs when invoking deletion logic - ```21/08/30 07:35:01 INFO TableWriter: Wrote 1 rows to test. word_groups in 0.028 s. ``` and ```07:14:17,862 SSTable.java:105 - Deleting sstable: /data/cassandra/data/test/word_groups-212f6d30b6ba11ea9c982b4b549ae647/md-5947-big``` Could you please let me what could be the issue ?

Comment: Also i tried running the nodetool compact test word_group

Comment: if data stays there, then something is wrong with deletion logic. When I tested with your data sample, everything was deleted. Another possible issue could be the not synchronized time on the spark & cassandra nodes - if you write data from the node that has timestamp from the future, then Spark attempts to delete data, but will have no effect because the timestamp of deletion marker is before the inserted data

Comment: One more question -  I want to delete the specific column but without knowing the values. I mean to say is I have a data frame and I need to delete the specific column. It is possible with the known values using this ```sc.parallelize(Seq(("animal", "mammoth")))
  .deleteFromCassandra("test", "word_groups", SomeColumns("count"))``` but how to delete without knowing the values("animal", "mammoth") ? something like ```df.select(primarykeys).deleteFromCassandra("test", "word_groups", SomeColumns("count"))``` is it possible like this ?

Comment: `testDF.withColumn("count", lit(null).cast("string"))` and `write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(test_table ++ Map("confirm.truncate" -> "false")).mode(SaveMode.Append).save()` I'm doing like this is this right way?

Comment: in this case you can follow your original approach - read data from table, change what is necessary, save back - but this will be too big overhead, as you basically duplicate your data. Or you can call `deleteFromCassandra` with a specific column - it's in the docs