# Spark on Cassandra : is there a way to remove data by partition key?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

The spark Cassandra connector has the `RDD.deleteFromCassandra(keyspaceName, tableName)` method.

> The values in the RDD are interpreted as *Primary Key* constraints.

I have a table like that :

```sql
CREATE TABLE table (a int, b int, c int, PRIMARY KEY (a,b));
```

As you can see, `a` is the `partition key`, and `b` the `clustering key`.

I need to have a `spark app` that remove efficiently by `partition_key`, and not by `primary key`.

Indeed, my goal is to always drop entire partitions by their `partition keys`, and not create a thombstones for each `primary key`.

How to do that with spark connector ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do if you specify `keyColumns` parameter to the `.deleteFromCassandra` function ([docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#example-deleting-a-range-from-a-partition)). For example, if you have composite partition key consisting of two columns `part1` & `part2`:

```scala
rdd.deleteFromCassandra("keyspace", "table", 
  keyColumns = SomeColumns("part1", "part2"))
```

This method works only with RDDs, if you use DataFrames, then you just need to do `df.rdd`.  Also, in some versions of connector, you may need to restrict selection just to partition columns - see discussion in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68739086/spark-scala-cassandra-connector-delete-all-all-rows-is-failing-with-illegalargum/68739600#68739600).